# Merge map and list to get a tuple3?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `Map[String,String]` and I have a `List[String]`.
I want to merge both of them to make a `Tuple[String , String , String]`.
What is the most efficient way to achieve this? I tried doing this but it doesnt work :

```
val queryTimeMap = logToMap(reqSlowQueryData)
    val iter = qNumber.iterator
    val tup : Tuple3[String , String , String]= queryTimeMap.map(element=> {
      (element._1, element._2 , iter.next())
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a for comprehension given

```
Map( "a"->"aa", "b"->"bb" )
m: Map(a -> aa, b -> bb)

val l = List( "x", "y" )
l: List(x, y)
```

like this,

```
for ( ((k,v),i) <- m zip l ) yield (k,v,i)
res: List((a,aa,x), (b,bb,y))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the below which uses a view to avoid creating an intermediate collection (via zip):

```
val map: Map[String, String] = Map("abc"-> "ABC", "def" -> "DEF", "ghi" -> "GHI")
val list: List[String] = List("One", "Two", "Three")
val combined: List[Tuple3[String, String, String]] = map.view.zip(list).map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2)).toList
```